# ember delete record, not able to delete after first attempt

Tags: ember.js

I have a workflow in which I have to delete a record, but in case back-end throws any error then I show an error dialog with a close button on it. The user can close that error dialog and go back to the main screen where he can again submit the action for deleting the record. But I am getting the following error when I try to click on delete for the second time:

> Attempted to handle event `deleteRecord` while in state root.deleted.inFlight

Can someone guide me what can be the potential issue?

My code for reference:

File: component.js

```
let person = this.get('person') -> this is the model

person.destroyRecord().then(() => {
// if success, show success message
   this.showSuccessModel();
}, (error) => {
// show error message in a dialog, with close button
   this.showErrorModel();
});
```

When user clicks on close button, and when he click on delete action again, then I am getting the error above.

Comment: It really helps if you can provide relevant code (especially route and controller code) otherwise we'll just be making speculative guesses.

Comment: Are you trying find record and then deleted it without waiting for data to be delivered ? Try to perform deleteRecord inside `then()`. But you need to provide more details in order to help you

Comment: @casafred I have added my code, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: No problem. Glad to see you were able to find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix the issue, in case of errors, I was using rollBackAttributes() function on the model object as suggested by ember documentation but just realized I also have to do:

model.send('becameInvalid'), as otherwise just rolling back Attributes does not work. So, my working code will look something like this:

```
let person = this.get('person') -> this is the model

person.destroyRecord().then(() => {
// if success, show success message
this.showSuccessModel();
}, (error) => {
// show error message in a dialog, with close button
   if(person.get('hasDirtyAttributes') {
     person.send('becameInvalid');
     person.rollBackAttributes();
   }
   this.showErrorModel();
});
```